# Can I improve network speed with VirtualBox between host and guest?

Tags: network, performance, virtualbox

I use a VirtualBox machine with Arch Linux as development web server. I want to improve rsync transfer speed via smb://. What kind of configuration is best to improve file transfer/synchronization?

Which network configuration is best for speed between the host and the guest?

My config:
Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Adaptador em ponte (bridged), en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort))

Comment: If I understand this right: You are running VirtualBox on an OS X host and mounting Arch Linux drives from OS X via Samba, correct?

Comment: Yes. A script mounts the samba share and runs rsync after.

Comment: Have you considered using VirtualBox's shared folder support instead?

Comment: I haven't thought about that.

Comment: I seems that I would lose my portability using shared folders. Meaning if I copy the virtual machine to my notebook it wouldn't work because the files are not stored inside the vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than `smb://` would be to NFS mount your shares over a private network interface running the [virtio-net drivers](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). Once mounted, inside the host OS, you'd rsync in the data with:

```
rsync /some/mount/point /home/myuser/
```

Or whatever you wanted.

Someone already mentioned [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and, on its own it won't speed up your VirtualBox setup, but it does make doing things like mounting in [shares on your Mac via NFS export](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) *much, much* easier than doing it by hand.

For example, here's a Vagrantfile that ups [an Arch Linux installation](https://vagrantcloud.com/losingkeys/arch) and mounts your Documents directory on your machine via NFS using virtio drivers to `/documents` on the image.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "losingkeys/arch"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype1', 'virtio']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype2', 'virtio']
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    vb.memory = 1024
    vb.cpus   = 2
    # Uncomment this to run in not-headless mode
    # vb.gui  = true
  end
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', type: 'nfs'
  config.vm.synced_folder File.join(ENV['HOME'], 'Documents'), "/documents", type: "nfs"
end
```

It requires root priveledges to work. You'll need to add:

```
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD = /usr/bin/tee -a /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD = /sbin/nfsd restart
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE = /usr/bin/sed -E -e /*/ d -ibak /etc/exports
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD, VAGRANT_NFSD, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE
```

to your sudoers file via `visudo` for it to work.

Once you've put that Vagrantfile on disk all you have to do is cd to the directory where you saved it and run `vagrant up` and you're in business. To connect it's `vagrant ssh` or you can uncomment that line I left in there to run it with a display head.

That's the fastest configuration I know of for host/guest I/O with VirtualBox running Linux as a guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly the answer you are looking for, but an alternative approach that works wonders for my development environments.

Vagrant ([vagrantup.com](http://vagrantup.com)) is a tool built on VirtualBox which facilitates using virtual machines for development environments. Once you installed it, you can navigate to a local folder with your source files in the terminal, and initialize your virtual machine. Vagrant will map the current folder by default to "/vagrant" inside the virtual machine with read-write access, through VirtualBox's shared folder support. You could then point the webroot inside your virtual machine to a folder below there, for example.

Have a look at the [Get Started](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/index.html) guide for more info on Vagrant. If you prefer Arch Linux, you can also find prebuilt boxes at [www.vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es/). You can even build your own box from scratch, in which case you might want to look at [this chapter](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html) in the manual.

As for portability, I believe it is not such a good idea to distribute your sources inside a virtual machine this way (even for a single developer). You should put those in a version control system like Git or SVN, and have a check-out on every machine where you want to develop on.

Comment: Looks promissing mainly because it has the name of the only RPG that I played (liked). :)

Comment: Note the default folder sharing is not very fast, but Vagrant has an option to use NFS instead. See the Vagrant wiki for info on this.

Comment: Vagarant, while it makes the configuration of VirtualBox instances easier, doesn't actually do anything to improve the I/O performance between the host and guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into an I/O bottleneck, I would recommend putting the VM on it's own hard drive.  Either that or upgrade to an SSD for improved disk I/O performance.